# I’m confused if ‘from’ in this sentence necessary or I can omit it

Tags: grammar, word-usage

> There are two options to choose from for the add-on you want to build alongside a Science Facility in Starcraft 1.

I’m confused if ‘from’ there is necessary or I can omit it. Besides:

> There are two options to choose which add-on you want to build alongside a Science Facility in Starcraft 1.

I’ve revised the sentence and I wonder which one is a more natural way of saying it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both sentences could be correct, but may have different implications.

---

Your first option:

> There are two options to choose from for the add-on you want to build alongside a Science Facility in Starcraft 1.

unambiguously means that
**a)** The "options" refer to different kinds of "add-on" you can build
**b)** There are *exactly two* of these "options"

Your second sentence:

> There are two options to choose which add-on you want to build alongside a Science Facility in Starcraft 1.

*could* be interpreted as having the same meaning as the first, but in this case it's a **less clear way of expressing that idea**. This is because it's **ambiguous** with regards to what the word "options" refers to. The sentence might also mean that
**a)** The "options" are some kind of selectable UI element (buttons, drop-down menu items, etc.) which allow the user to specify their choice of "add-on" to build
**b)** There are two such "options": but, within each option, it is not specified how many choices of buildable "add-on" there are to choose between

---

***So***, if you intend to state that the user only has two choices of add-on to build, and must choose one of them, I would recommend keeping the **first** sentence.

Comment: Thank you for the perfect explanation!!